# disable SSH interactive login

Tags: ubuntu, login, ssh

I'd like to conditionally disable interactive logins in ubuntu in the event that a user attempts to login to an ssh shell with an invalid username.

Say I have a user 'bob' on my server, but the user 'fred; is not a valid user.

When bob logs in with

```
ssh bob@my_ip_address
```

I want an interactive login

When someone signs in with

```
ssh fred@my_ip_address
```

I don't want any interactive login and the login attempt to terminate.

How can one do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: I would strongly discourage you from doing this. It's basically one step away from a SSH user-selection list.

Comment: You should use keys and eliminate the interactive logins altougher. Also, you will probably get more responses on serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to do this. OTOH, [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) does just about exactly what you want. You can set it up to detect and ban IPs that attempt login as an invalid user for a certain period of time.

joet3ch is also correct in saying switching to public-private key login only would be the most secure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that this way it would be very easy to find a valid username? You always want any attacker to have as little information about your system as possible!
As an alternative to fail2ban, you could also use `denyhosts` looks like it would do the exact same as fail2ban.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you can use the `AllowUsers` parameter to specify which users are allowed to login via SSH:

```
AllowUsers
             This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces.  If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns.  Only
             user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not recognized.  By default, login is allowed for all users.  If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are
             separately checked, restricting logins to particular users from particular hosts.  The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers,
             DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.

             See PATTERNS in ssh_config(5) for more information on patterns.
```

Also, I'd really recommend using SSH keys instead of passwords to secure the connections.